# node.js what is requirejs module

Tags: node.js, requirejs

i downloaded an example about using nodejs and requirejs. Consider this snippet code.

```
define(['express', 'module', 'path'], function (express, module, path) {
  var app = express.createServer();

  app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.logger({ format: ':method :url :status' }));
    var filename = module.uri;
    app.use(express.static(path.dirname(filename) + '/static'));
  });

  return app;
});
```

what is here the module "module"?  When i look in my depencies file, "module" doesn't exist.

```
{
  "name": "node-requirejs-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.0",
    "requirejs": ">=1.0.0",
    "socket.io": ">=0.8.7",
    "underscore": ">=1.2.1"
  }
}
```

when i gonna use requirejs then is underscore important?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't have to list a version dependency for every module.  It will simply check your modules folder for a module (inappropriately) named "module".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specially named requirejs dependency called 'module' which you can use to look up additional information from the requirejs internals. This is typically used for passing additional configuration data. From the [requirejs config api documentation](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig):

> There is a common need to pass configuration info to a module. That configuration info is usually known as part of the application, and there needs to be a way to pass that down to a module. In RequireJS, that is done with the config option for requirejs.config(). Modules can then read that info by asking for the special dependency "module" and calling module.config().

See also [Magic Modules](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#wiki-magic) from the wiki:

> This module gives you information about the module ID and location of the current module:

In that section, he has an example of using module.uri, like in your original code snippet:

```
define(['module'], function(module){
    console.log(module.id);
    console.log(module.uri);
});
```